# Suggestions for insert with Foreign key constraint in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table containing 2 entries.

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE  `db`.`main` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

The id for these 2 entries are automatically generated primary keys.

I have another table with a rule linking

```
CREATE TABLE  `db`.`day` (
    `main_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `day` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_db_main` FOREIGN KEY (`main_id`) REFERENCES `main` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

now I can successfully get a result using

```
SELECT * FROM main where id='9';
```

but when I try to run

```
INSERT INTO day (main_id, day) VALUES (9, 0);
```

I get

"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`day`, CONSTRAINT `fk_db_main` FOREIGN KEY (`main_id`) REFERENCES `main` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) (1452)"

Any suggestions on what I am missing with the insert?

**I hadn't listed the actual cause of the issue while asking the question.  The actual cause was that the main db table was in MyISAM, and the InnoDB tables couldn't create a foreign key connecting to it.  In short, MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys, even when they are coming from other tables.

Comment: The insert statement looks fine.

Comment: I'm puzzled that you think there are two 'entries' in the 'main' table.  To my way of thinking, there is one column - called ID - and it is also the primary key of the table.

Comment: Also, why do you quote the '9' in the SELECT?  And what result do you get when you run the SELECT?

Comment: I get back a 9.  The quotes don't make any difference, it was just something I happened to be testing when I couldn't figure out the issue.

Comment: No solution yet because I don't understand the problem. (The sql works without the constraint, so I'll do the sanity checking in the software for now. I removed the constraint for the short term, this will let me continue.

Comment: Found the actual problem is that InnoDB tables can't link to MyISAM tables, and the main table was preexisting, which I hadn't mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't listed the actual cause of the issue while asking the question. The actual cause was that the main db table was in MyISAM, and the InnoDB tables couldn't create a foreign key connecting to it. In short, MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys, even when they are coming from other tables.

Answer (score 2):

The insert works for me if I remove the `db.` parts in the `CREATE TABLE` statements (and insert into `main` a row with an `id` of 9).  Maybe the problem is that you're using that `db.` prefix inconsistently, i.e. after `TABLE` but not in the `CONSTRAINT` clause...?

Comment: +1 Yep, I was going to suggest double-checking which database you're querying.

Comment: Are you saying the creation of a trigger wouldn't cause issues if the data it depended on doesn't exist?  I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

The FOREIGN KEY constraint says "there shall be an entry in the 'main` table with an ID value that matches the newly inserted 'main_id' value in the 'day' table".

When you INSERT the value 9 into 'day', is there already a row in 'main' with ID = 9?

The DBMS doesn't think so - that's why it complained.

Comment: Yes, selecting the id of value 9 from main where id equals 9 is returning 9.

Comment: OK - then I think Alex Martelli is on the right track.  There is some other table called `main` than just the one called `db`.`main`, and your foreign key is not referencing the table you think it is.